# Function that stops tftp server

Tags: python, automation

New to python here
Tried the following

```
import tftpy

import threading

def TftpServer (rootFolder, interface IP='10.0.0.0', port=69): print("started TftpServer")

server = tftpy. TftpServer (rootFolder)

server.listen(interfaceIP, port)

def startTftp(rootFolder):

lisnterThread = threading. Thread (target-TftpServer, args=(rootFolder,))

LisnterThread.start()
```

When I invoke startTftp the server starts listening , I tried multiple ways to write a function that stops the server but with no success

I tried using multiprocess and setting a bool global var that will stop the function

I'm trying to write a kill function

Eg

KillTftp()
Print ("stopped listening")

And the server will stop

The end goal is for the kill TFTP to be imported to another file

Comment: you can use a shared flag between the server thread and the main thread server thread will periodically check the flag and gracefully exit when it detects the flag is set